# Next-Auth: getSession returns null

Tags: curl, next.js, next-auth

API request for the below code through a browser works fine i.e. returns `{"success":true,"data":{"user": ...}}` but using cURL or REST-Client VS Code extension return null i.e. `{"success":true,"data":null}`.
Below is the code where I return the session object through `/api/query` endpoint:

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: session });
};
```

I tried getting the session using the endpoint `/api/auth/session` too. The endpoint returns the session using the browser but returns null using cURL.
Here is the cURL request `curl http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session`.
What's the reason for the behavior?
P.S. : I am using Google OAuth for authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auth depends on cookies, your browser automatically sends the cookies. But when you use cURL cookies are not present, hence auth cannot authenticate.
[Next-Auth cookies](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#cookies)

Comment: Cookies can be included in curl requests. Please see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76876963/3542457) for an example of doing so.

Answer (score 3):

In `next-auth` v4, getting the clients session in a Middleware is currently not supported. You can use [the built in Middleware methods](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/nextjs#middleware) (which will eventually hit the `getToken` method) - or use [`getToken`](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#using-gettoken) yourself.

I myself feel that this should be highlighted more in the documentation.

Source: [This reddit post with an approved comment from lrobinson, VP of Developer Experience @ Vercel](https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/sw5htj/comment/hxkcx4a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 1):

There is curl support for cookies. I have used the following to authenticate using curl and the NextAuth credential provider:

```
API_URL=http://localhost:3000

# CSRF token curl can parsed manually or with SED if JQ not installed
CSRF_TOKEN=$(curl -c /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt -b /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt $API_URL/api/auth/csrf | jq -r '.csrfToken')

# Login
curl -v \
  -d "username=agoodusername&password=agoodpassword&csrfToken=${CSRF_TOKEN}" \
  -c /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt \
  -b /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt \
  $API_URL/api/auth/callback/credentials

# Logout
curl -v \
  -d "csrfToken=${CSRF_TOKEN}" \
  -c /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt \
  -b /tmp/nextauth-cookies.txt \
  $API_URL/api/auth/signout
```

`agoodusername` and `agoodpassword` should both be updated (URL-encoded values).

NextAuth uses the [double submit method to prevent CSRF attacks](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#get-apiauthcsrf), so CSRF token needs to be included in form data as well as request cookies.

Answer (score 0):

create file: ' .eslintrc.json ' in the root of the application with the following contents:

```
{
  "env":{"browser": true, "node":true, "es6":true},
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended","next/core-web-vitals"]
}
```